# Does stylelint has a rule to detect unknown values?

Tags: stylelint

I'm new to Stylelint and I see that it has a rule to identify unknown CSS units.

I can't find a rule that warns about the use of unknown values.

for example:
`align-items: wrongValue;`

See attached
[Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuRHM.png) that shows Stylint warns me about wrong CSS unit type but not on wrong CSS value

Does Stylelint have such a rule?

If not, what can I do to prevent these potential errors?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are defaults, but it looks like you can customize what are acceptable values using the `declaration-property-value-allowed-list` in your stylelint configuration file.

https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list/declaration-property-value-allowed-list

Something like this would only allow use of `stretch` or `center`:

```
{
  "align-items": ["stretch","center"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[CSSTree](https://github.com/csstree/csstree) has a built-in lexer that can test CSS against syntaxes defined by W3C.

It can be used within stylelint using the [`stylelint-csstree-validator` plugin](https://github.com/csstree/stylelint-validator):

```
// .stylelintrc.js
{
  "plugins": [
    "stylelint-csstree-validator"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "csstree/validator": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
I'm curious why Stylelint isn't shipped out of the box with this validation (as a rule).
Look to me as an important thing to validate.

Answer (score 0):

Stylelint 15 added the `declaration-property-value-no-unknown` rule: https://stylelint.io/migration-guide/to-15/#added-declaration-property-value-no-unknown-rule

```
{
  "extends": ["stylelint-config-standard"],
  "rules": {
+   "declaration-property-value-no-unknown": true
    ..
   }
}
```

When enabled, this rule will warn you about invalid values like this one:

```css
a {
  top: red;
}
```